# ORA-01008: not all variables bound when executing merge statement in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle, cx-oracle

I'm currently trying to ingest data from files in an SFTP location into their respective Oracle tables. I've used **cx_oracle** library to create the necessary connection and to execute the queries. In this use case, I'm trying to run a **MERGE** statement into the table by using DUAL.

```
for i, row in dataset.iterrows():
    merge_sql = "MERGE INTO schema.{} USING DUAL ON ( SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID = :1 ) " \
                "WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET {} " \
                "WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT({}) VALUES({})".format(self.source_table_name,
                                                                     set_stmt_sql_list_as_str,
                                                                     col_names_as_str,
                                                                     col_list_from_df_as_str)

    oracle_cursor.execute(merge_sql, tuple(row))
```

In the above snippet, **dataset** is the dataframe which was created after reading the file from the SFTP location.

The merge_sql string looks like below after replacing the values:

```
MERGE INTO schema.table USING DUAL ON ( SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID = :1 )
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET FILE_ID_2=:0,SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID=:1,ACCOUNT_NUMBER_PART1=:2,ACCOUNT_NUMBER_PART2=:3,CONTACT_TYPE=:4,CDM_ACTION_CODE=:5,ACCOUNT_HOLDER_NAME=:6,CREDIT_CARD_TYPE=:7,CARD_HOLDER_NAME=:8,CC_TOKEN=:9,CREDIT_CARD_MASKED=:10,CREDIT_CARD_EXPIRY=:11,BP_ROLE=:12,BP_ROLE_END_DATE=:13,CUST_CREDIT_STATUS=:14,BLOCKED_REASON=:15,CREDIT_LIMIT=:16,ANALYST_OR_COLLECTOR_COD=:17,CREDIT_REVIEW_DATE=:18,STOP_ORDER_ENTRY=:19,EMAIL_ADDRESS=:20,CITY_NAME=:21,COUNTRY_CODE=:22,FAX_NUMBER=:23,PO_BOX=:24,CITY_POSTAL_CODE=:25,STATE_CODE=:26,ADDRESS_LINE_2=:27,ADDRESS_LINE_1=:28,TELEPHONE_NUMBER=:29,LAST_NAME=:30,FIRST_NAME=:31,CONTACT_PERSON_FUNC=:32,NOTES=:33,SALUTATION=:34,VALID_FROM=:35,VALID_TO=:36,BUSINESS_PARTNER_REL=:37,RECONCILIATION_ACCNT=:38,CUST_SERV_CONT_SALUT=:39,STATEMENT_CODE=:40,TERMS_CODE=:41,DUNNING_LEVEL=:42,DUNNING_BLOCK=:43,CURRENT_DUNNING_LVL=:44,UC_FLAG=:45,CUSTOMER_CITY=:46,CUSTOMER_COUNTRY_COD=:47,CUSTOMER_FAX_NUM=:48,CUSTOMER_PO_BOX=:49,CUSTOMER_ZIP_CODE=:50,CUSTOMER_STATE=:51,CUSTOMER_ADDR_LINE_2=:52,CUSTOMER_ADDR_LINE_1=:53,COMPANY_NAME=:54,VALIDITY_START_DATE=:55,VALIDITY_END_DATE=:56,VALIDEND_BP_ROLE_DATE=:57,EXTERNAL_ACCT_NUMBER=:58,SOURCE_SYSTEM_NAME=:59,PROCESS_FLAG=:60,FILE_NM=:61,FILE_LOAD_DATE=:62,IND_ORG_FLAG=:63,LEGACY_ID=:64 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT(FILE_ID_2,SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID,ACCOUNT_NUMBER_PART1,ACCOUNT_NUMBER_PART2,CONTACT_TYPE,CDM_ACTION_CODE,ACCOUNT_HOLDER_NAME,CREDIT_CARD_TYPE,CARD_HOLDER_NAME,CC_TOKEN,CREDIT_CARD_MASKED,CREDIT_CARD_EXPIRY,BP_ROLE,BP_ROLE_END_DATE,CUST_CREDIT_STATUS,BLOCKED_REASON,CREDIT_LIMIT,ANALYST_OR_COLLECTOR_COD,CREDIT_REVIEW_DATE,STOP_ORDER_ENTRY,EMAIL_ADDRESS,CITY_NAME,COUNTRY_CODE,FAX_NUMBER,PO_BOX,CITY_POSTAL_CODE,STATE_CODE,ADDRESS_LINE_2,ADDRESS_LINE_1,TELEPHONE_NUMBER,LAST_NAME,FIRST_NAME,CONTACT_PERSON_FUNC,NOTES,SALUTATION,VALID_FROM,VALID_TO,BUSINESS_PARTNER_REL,RECONCILIATION_ACCNT,CUST_SERV_CONT_SALUT,STATEMENT_CODE,TERMS_CODE,DUNNING_LEVEL,DUNNING_BLOCK,CURRENT_DUNNING_LVL,UC_FLAG,CUSTOMER_CITY,CUSTOMER_COUNTRY_COD,CUSTOMER_FAX_NUM,CUSTOMER_PO_BOX,CUSTOMER_ZIP_CODE,CUSTOMER_STATE,CUSTOMER_ADDR_LINE_2,CUSTOMER_ADDR_LINE_1,COMPANY_NAME,VALIDITY_START_DATE,VALIDITY_END_DATE,VALIDEND_BP_ROLE_DATE,EXTERNAL_ACCT_NUMBER,SOURCE_SYSTEM_NAME,PROCESS_FLAG,FILE_NM,FILE_LOAD_DATE,IND_ORG_FLAG,LEGACY_ID) 
VALUES(:0,:1,:2,:3,:4,:5,:6,:7,:8,:9,:10,:11,:12,:13,:14,:15,:16,:17,:18,:19,:20,:21,:22,:23,:24,:25,:26,:27,:28,:29,:30,:31,:32,:33,:34,:35,:36,:37,:38,:39,:40,:41,:42,:43,:44,:45,:46,:47,:48,:49,:50,:51,:52,:53,:54,:55,:56,:57,:58,:59,:60,:61,:62,:63,:64)
```

When I'm trying to execute the above SQL, the following error throws up

> ORA-01008: not all variables bound

Where as when I tried the same approach for a simple **INSERT** like below, it worked perfectly:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO PWC_ADMIN.{}({}) VALUES({})" \
                        .format(self.source_table_name, col_names_as_str, col_list_from_df_as_str)
```

Including the DDL of the table that i'm trying to merge for reference:

```
CREATE TABLE "schema"."table" 
   (    "FILE_ID_2" VARCHAR2(3 CHAR), 
    "SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID" VARCHAR2(30 CHAR), 
    "ACCOUNT_NUMBER_PART1" VARCHAR2(7 CHAR), 
    "ACCOUNT_NUMBER_PART2" VARCHAR2(4 CHAR), 
    "CONTACT_TYPE" VARCHAR2(4 CHAR), 
    "CDM_ACTION_CODE" VARCHAR2(3 CHAR), 
    "ACCOUNT_HOLDER_NAME" VARCHAR2(100 CHAR), 
    "CREDIT_CARD_TYPE" VARCHAR2(2 CHAR), 
    "CARD_HOLDER_NAME" VARCHAR2(50), 
    "CC_TOKEN" VARCHAR2(24 CHAR), 
    "CREDIT_CARD_MASKED" VARCHAR2(19 CHAR), 
    "CREDIT_CARD_EXPIRY" VARCHAR2(4 CHAR), 
    "BP_ROLE" VARCHAR2(6 CHAR), 
    "BP_ROLE_END_DATE" VARCHAR2(8 CHAR), 
    "CUST_CREDIT_STATUS" CHAR(1), 
    "BLOCKED_REASON" VARCHAR2(25 CHAR), 
    "CREDIT_LIMIT" NUMBER(11,2), 
    "ANALYST_OR_COLLECTOR_COD" VARCHAR2(4 CHAR), 
    "CREDIT_REVIEW_DATE" NUMBER(7,0), 
    "STOP_ORDER_ENTRY" CHAR(1), 
    "EMAIL_ADDRESS" VARCHAR2(50 CHAR), 
    "CITY_NAME" VARCHAR2(24 CHAR), 
    "COUNTRY_CODE" VARCHAR2(4 CHAR), 
    "FAX_NUMBER" VARCHAR2(15 CHAR), 
    "PO_BOX" VARCHAR2(25 CHAR), 
    "CITY_POSTAL_CODE" VARCHAR2(9 CHAR), 
    "STATE_CODE" VARCHAR2(2 CHAR), 
    "ADDRESS_LINE_2" VARCHAR2(50 CHAR), 
    "ADDRESS_LINE_1" VARCHAR2(50 CHAR), 
    "TELEPHONE_NUMBER" VARCHAR2(15 CHAR), 
    "LAST_NAME" VARCHAR2(30 CHAR), 
    "FIRST_NAME" VARCHAR2(20 CHAR), 
    "CONTACT_PERSON_FUNC" VARCHAR2(2 CHAR), 
    "NOTES" VARCHAR2(60 CHAR), 
    "SALUTATION" VARCHAR2(2 CHAR), 
    "VALID_FROM" VARCHAR2(8 CHAR), 
    "VALID_TO" VARCHAR2(8 CHAR), 
    "BUSINESS_PARTNER_REL" VARCHAR2(6 CHAR), 
    "RECONCILIATION_ACCNT" VARCHAR2(8 CHAR), 
    "CUST_SERV_CONT_SALUT" CHAR(1), 
    "STATEMENT_CODE" CHAR(1), 
    "TERMS_CODE" VARCHAR2(2 CHAR), 
    "DUNNING_LEVEL" CHAR(1), 
    "DUNNING_BLOCK" CHAR(1), 
    "CURRENT_DUNNING_LVL" CHAR(1), 
    "UC_FLAG" CHAR(1), 
    "CUSTOMER_CITY" VARCHAR2(24 CHAR), 
    "CUSTOMER_COUNTRY_COD" VARCHAR2(4 CHAR), 
    "CUSTOMER_FAX_NUM" VARCHAR2(15 CHAR), 
    "CUSTOMER_PO_BOX" VARCHAR2(25 CHAR), 
    "CUSTOMER_ZIP_CODE" VARCHAR2(9 CHAR), 
    "CUSTOMER_STATE" VARCHAR2(2 CHAR), 
    "CUSTOMER_ADDR_LINE_2" VARCHAR2(30 CHAR), 
    "CUSTOMER_ADDR_LINE_1" VARCHAR2(30 CHAR), 
    "COMPANY_NAME" VARCHAR2(50 CHAR), 
    "VALIDITY_START_DATE" VARCHAR2(8 CHAR), 
    "VALIDITY_END_DATE" VARCHAR2(8 CHAR), 
    "VALIDEND_BP_ROLE_DATE" VARCHAR2(8 CHAR), 
    "EXTERNAL_ACCT_NUMBER" VARCHAR2(25 CHAR), 
    "SOURCE_SYSTEM_NAME" VARCHAR2(10 CHAR), 
    "PROCESS_FLAG" CHAR(1), 
    "FILE_NM" VARCHAR2(256 CHAR), 
    "FILE_LOAD_DATE" DATE, 
    "IND_ORG_FLAG" CHAR(1), 
    "LEGACY_ID" VARCHAR2(25 CHAR)
   );
```

I've tried looking for reasons here in SO and else where, plus tried debugging whether I'm missing anything in those lists which I'm replacing in the SQL, I weren't able to succeed. Has anyone come across this type of issue? If so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As ORA-01008 says: there is a mismatch in the variable mappings. You have to dig deeper to find out why. If you google "python ORA-01008" you'll find a lot of hints where to start and how to debug similar issues. To get further help here you need to add the table layout.

Comment: ... preferably with a SQL DDL create table.

Comment: @IODEV thnx for the input. I actually cross checked the mappings tho and it seems to be ok. But i'll do a recheck. I've added the DDL as well for you reference

Comment: It may also be a column data type mismatch caused by for instance the mapping order or mixing named with positional params where positional parameters need to come first. See @SayanMalakshinov answer down below.

Comment: Using named binds can avoid problems with misunderstandings of how numbered binds works, and with duplicate use of binds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be much easier and more readable if you would bind variables just once,  like this:

```sql
for i, row in dataset.iterrows():
    merge_sql = "MERGE INTO schema.{} dst " \
                "USING (SELECT {} DUAL) src " \
                "ON ( dst.SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID = src.SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID ) " \
                "WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET {} " \
                "WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT({}) VALUES({})".format(self.source_table_name,
                                                                     using_stmt_sql_list_as_str,
                                                                     set_stmt_sql_list_as_str,
                                                                     col_names_as_str,
                                                                     col_names_as_str)

    oracle_cursor.execute(merge_sql, tuple(row))
```

where `using_stmt_sql_list_as_str` is

```
:0 as FILE_ID_2
:1 as SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID
:2 as ACCOUNT_NUMBER_PART1
:3 as ACCOUNT_NUMBER_PART2
:4 as CONTACT_TYPE
:5 as CDM_ACTION_CODE
:6 as ACCOUNT_HOLDER_NAME
:7 as CREDIT_CARD_TYPE
:8 as CARD_HOLDER_NAME
:9 as CC_TOKEN
:10 as CREDIT_CARD_MASKED
:11 as CREDIT_CARD_EXPIRY
:12 as BP_ROLE
:13 as BP_ROLE_END_DATE
:14 as CUST_CREDIT_STATUS
:15 as BLOCKED_REASON
:16 as CREDIT_LIMIT
:17 as ANALYST_OR_COLLECTOR_COD
:18 as CREDIT_REVIEW_DATE
:19 as STOP_ORDER_ENTRY
:20 as EMAIL_ADDRESS
:21 as CITY_NAME
:22 as COUNTRY_CODE
:23 as FAX_NUMBER
:24 as PO_BOX
:25 as CITY_POSTAL_CODE
:26 as STATE_CODE
:27 as ADDRESS_LINE_2
:28 as ADDRESS_LINE_1
:29 as TELEPHONE_NUMBER
:30 as LAST_NAME
:31 as FIRST_NAME
:32 as CONTACT_PERSON_FUNC
:33 as NOTES
:34 as SALUTATION
:35 as VALID_FROM
:36 as VALID_TO
:37 as BUSINESS_PARTNER_REL
:38 as RECONCILIATION_ACCNT
:39 as CUST_SERV_CONT_SALUT
:40 as STATEMENT_CODE
:41 as TERMS_CODE
:42 as DUNNING_LEVEL
:43 as DUNNING_BLOCK
:44 as CURRENT_DUNNING_LVL
:45 as UC_FLAG
:46 as CUSTOMER_CITY
:47 as CUSTOMER_COUNTRY_COD
:48 as CUSTOMER_FAX_NUM
:49 as CUSTOMER_PO_BOX
:50 as CUSTOMER_ZIP_CODE
:51 as CUSTOMER_STATE
:52 as CUSTOMER_ADDR_LINE_2
:53 as CUSTOMER_ADDR_LINE_1
:54 as COMPANY_NAME
:55 as VALIDITY_START_DATE
:56 as VALIDITY_END_DATE
:57 as VALIDEND_BP_ROLE_DATE
:58 as EXTERNAL_ACCT_NUMBER
:59 as SOURCE_SYSTEM_NAME
:60 as PROCESS_FLAG
:61 as FILE_NM
:62 as FILE_LOAD_DATE
:63 as IND_ORG_FLAG
:64 as LEGACY_ID
```

and `set_stmt_sql_list_as_str`:

```
dst.FILE_ID_2=src.FILE_ID_2,
dst.ACCOUNT_NUMBER_PART1=src.ACCOUNT_NUMBER_PART1,
dst.ACCOUNT_NUMBER_PART2=src.ACCOUNT_NUMBER_PART2,
dst.CONTACT_TYPE=src.CONTACT_TYPE,
dst.CDM_ACTION_CODE=src.CDM_ACTION_CODE,
dst.ACCOUNT_HOLDER_NAME=src.ACCOUNT_HOLDER_NAME,
dst.CREDIT_CARD_TYPE=src.CREDIT_CARD_TYPE,
dst.CARD_HOLDER_NAME=src.CARD_HOLDER_NAME,
dst.CC_TOKEN=src.CC_TOKEN,
dst.CREDIT_CARD_MASKED=src.CREDIT_CARD_MASKED,
dst.CREDIT_CARD_EXPIRY=src.CREDIT_CARD_EXPIRY,
dst.BP_ROLE=src.BP_ROLE,
dst.BP_ROLE_END_DATE=src.BP_ROLE_END_DATE,
dst.CUST_CREDIT_STATUS=src.CUST_CREDIT_STATUS,
dst.BLOCKED_REASON=src.BLOCKED_REASON,
dst.CREDIT_LIMIT=src.CREDIT_LIMIT,
dst.ANALYST_OR_COLLECTOR_COD=src.ANALYST_OR_COLLECTOR_COD,
dst.CREDIT_REVIEW_DATE=src.CREDIT_REVIEW_DATE,
dst.STOP_ORDER_ENTRY=src.STOP_ORDER_ENTRY,
dst.EMAIL_ADDRESS=src.EMAIL_ADDRESS,
dst.CITY_NAME=src.CITY_NAME,
dst.COUNTRY_CODE=src.COUNTRY_CODE,
dst.FAX_NUMBER=src.FAX_NUMBER,
dst.PO_BOX=src.PO_BOX,
dst.CITY_POSTAL_CODE=src.CITY_POSTAL_CODE,
dst.STATE_CODE=src.STATE_CODE,
dst.ADDRESS_LINE_2=src.ADDRESS_LINE_2,
dst.ADDRESS_LINE_1=src.ADDRESS_LINE_1,
dst.TELEPHONE_NUMBER=src.TELEPHONE_NUMBER,
dst.LAST_NAME=src.LAST_NAME,
dst.FIRST_NAME=src.FIRST_NAME,
dst.CONTACT_PERSON_FUNC=src.CONTACT_PERSON_FUNC,
dst.NOTES=src.NOTES,
dst.SALUTATION=src.SALUTATION,
dst.VALID_FROM=src.VALID_FROM,
dst.VALID_TO=src.VALID_TO,
dst.BUSINESS_PARTNER_REL=src.BUSINESS_PARTNER_REL,
dst.RECONCILIATION_ACCNT=src.RECONCILIATION_ACCNT,
dst.CUST_SERV_CONT_SALUT=src.CUST_SERV_CONT_SALUT,
dst.STATEMENT_CODE=src.STATEMENT_CODE,
dst.TERMS_CODE=src.TERMS_CODE,
dst.DUNNING_LEVEL=src.DUNNING_LEVEL,
dst.DUNNING_BLOCK=src.DUNNING_BLOCK,
dst.CURRENT_DUNNING_LVL=src.CURRENT_DUNNING_LVL,
dst.UC_FLAG=src.UC_FLAG,
dst.CUSTOMER_CITY=src.CUSTOMER_CITY,
dst.CUSTOMER_COUNTRY_COD=src.CUSTOMER_COUNTRY_COD,
dst.CUSTOMER_FAX_NUM=src.CUSTOMER_FAX_NUM,
dst.CUSTOMER_PO_BOX=src.CUSTOMER_PO_BOX,
dst.CUSTOMER_ZIP_CODE=src.CUSTOMER_ZIP_CODE,
dst.CUSTOMER_STATE=src.CUSTOMER_STATE,
dst.CUSTOMER_ADDR_LINE_2=src.CUSTOMER_ADDR_LINE_2,
dst.CUSTOMER_ADDR_LINE_1=src.CUSTOMER_ADDR_LINE_1,
dst.COMPANY_NAME=src.COMPANY_NAME,
dst.VALIDITY_START_DATE=src.VALIDITY_START_DATE,
dst.VALIDITY_END_DATE=src.VALIDITY_END_DATE,
dst.VALIDEND_BP_ROLE_DATE=src.VALIDEND_BP_ROLE_DATE,
dst.EXTERNAL_ACCT_NUMBER=src.EXTERNAL_ACCT_NUMBER,
dst.SOURCE_SYSTEM_NAME=src.SOURCE_SYSTEM_NAME,
dst.PROCESS_FLAG=src.PROCESS_FLAG,
dst.FILE_NM=src.FILE_NM,
dst.FILE_LOAD_DATE=src.FILE_LOAD_DATE,
dst.IND_ORG_FLAG=src.IND_ORG_FLAG,
dst.LEGACY_ID=src.LEGACY_ID
```

ie, you need to skip `dst.SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID=src.SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID,` since you can't change a column which is used for `ON(...)` match condition.

So your final merge statement looks like this:

```sql
MERGE INTO schema.table dst
USING ( select 
        :0 as FILE_ID_2,
        :1 as SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID,
        :2 as ACCOUNT_NUMBER_PART1,
        :3 as ACCOUNT_NUMBER_PART2,
        :4 as CONTACT_TYPE,
        ...
        from DUAL) src
ON ( dst.SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID = src.SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID )
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET 
dst.FILE_ID_2=src.FILE_ID_2,
dst.ACCOUNT_NUMBER_PART1=src.ACCOUNT_NUMBER_PART1,
dst.ACCOUNT_NUMBER_PART2=src.ACCOUNT_NUMBER_PART2,
...
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT(FILE_ID_2,SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID,ACCOUNT_NUMBER_PART1,ACCOUNT_NUMBER_PART2,CONTACT_TYPE,CDM_ACTION_CODE,ACCOUNT_HOLDER_NAME,CREDIT_CARD_TYPE,CARD_HOLDER_NAME,CC_TOKEN,CREDIT_CARD_MASKED,CREDIT_CARD_EXPIRY,BP_ROLE,BP_ROLE_END_DATE,CUST_CREDIT_STATUS,BLOCKED_REASON,CREDIT_LIMIT,ANALYST_OR_COLLECTOR_COD,CREDIT_REVIEW_DATE,STOP_ORDER_ENTRY,EMAIL_ADDRESS,CITY_NAME,COUNTRY_CODE,FAX_NUMBER,PO_BOX,CITY_POSTAL_CODE,STATE_CODE,ADDRESS_LINE_2,ADDRESS_LINE_1,TELEPHONE_NUMBER,LAST_NAME,FIRST_NAME,CONTACT_PERSON_FUNC,NOTES,SALUTATION,VALID_FROM,VALID_TO,BUSINESS_PARTNER_REL,RECONCILIATION_ACCNT,CUST_SERV_CONT_SALUT,STATEMENT_CODE,TERMS_CODE,DUNNING_LEVEL,DUNNING_BLOCK,CURRENT_DUNNING_LVL,UC_FLAG,CUSTOMER_CITY,CUSTOMER_COUNTRY_COD,CUSTOMER_FAX_NUM,CUSTOMER_PO_BOX,CUSTOMER_ZIP_CODE,CUSTOMER_STATE,CUSTOMER_ADDR_LINE_2,CUSTOMER_ADDR_LINE_1,COMPANY_NAME,VALIDITY_START_DATE,VALIDITY_END_DATE,VALIDEND_BP_ROLE_DATE,EXTERNAL_ACCT_NUMBER,SOURCE_SYSTEM_NAME,PROCESS_FLAG,FILE_NM,FILE_LOAD_DATE,IND_ORG_FLAG,LEGACY_ID) 
VALUES(FILE_ID_2,SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID,ACCOUNT_NUMBER_PART1,ACCOUNT_NUMBER_PART2,CONTACT_TYPE,CDM_ACTION_CODE,ACCOUNT_HOLDER_NAME,CREDIT_CARD_TYPE,CARD_HOLDER_NAME,CC_TOKEN,CREDIT_CARD_MASKED,CREDIT_CARD_EXPIRY,BP_ROLE,BP_ROLE_END_DATE,CUST_CREDIT_STATUS,BLOCKED_REASON,CREDIT_LIMIT,ANALYST_OR_COLLECTOR_COD,CREDIT_REVIEW_DATE,STOP_ORDER_ENTRY,EMAIL_ADDRESS,CITY_NAME,COUNTRY_CODE,FAX_NUMBER,PO_BOX,CITY_POSTAL_CODE,STATE_CODE,ADDRESS_LINE_2,ADDRESS_LINE_1,TELEPHONE_NUMBER,LAST_NAME,FIRST_NAME,CONTACT_PERSON_FUNC,NOTES,SALUTATION,VALID_FROM,VALID_TO,BUSINESS_PARTNER_REL,RECONCILIATION_ACCNT,CUST_SERV_CONT_SALUT,STATEMENT_CODE,TERMS_CODE,DUNNING_LEVEL,DUNNING_BLOCK,CURRENT_DUNNING_LVL,UC_FLAG,CUSTOMER_CITY,CUSTOMER_COUNTRY_COD,CUSTOMER_FAX_NUM,CUSTOMER_PO_BOX,CUSTOMER_ZIP_CODE,CUSTOMER_STATE,CUSTOMER_ADDR_LINE_2,CUSTOMER_ADDR_LINE_1,COMPANY_NAME,VALIDITY_START_DATE,VALIDITY_END_DATE,VALIDEND_BP_ROLE_DATE,EXTERNAL_ACCT_NUMBER,SOURCE_SYSTEM_NAME,PROCESS_FLAG,FILE_NM,FILE_LOAD_DATE,IND_ORG_FLAG,LEGACY_ID)
```

Comment: Thanks much @Sayan. This is really helpful. I followed your approach and when i tried to execute now it's throwing me **ORA-38101: Invalid column in the INSERT VALUES Clause: "PWC_ADMIN"."DST"."FILE_ID_2"**  Am I missing something?

Comment: @Kulasangar you don't need to specify schema and alias `DST` in values clause, remove schema and alias at all or specify `src` alias

Comment: I removed the all the DST aliases everywhere from the above SQL ( MERGE INTO schema.table
USING ( select 
        :0 as FILE_ID_2,
        :1 as SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID,
        ...
        from DUAL) src
ON ( dst.SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID = src.SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID )
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET 
FILE_ID_2=src.FILE_ID_2,
...
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN... 

But now i'm getting **ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined**

Comment: @Kulasangar OT: I'm sure you probably already thought about it but nevertheless important (and just a friendly advice): make sure the solution utilize encrypted credit card storage, app should only use references to it during normal operations, ie never work with or expose decrypted credit card info inside the app, temp-tables or files etc.

Comment: @IODEV absolutely.. that's a good point and it's taken care of :) thanks

Comment: @Kulasangar you **need** to use aliases in the right side of `when matched then update set` clause, otherwise oracle do not know which values to use for update

Comment: I'd suggest also to use `src.col` in the `insert` clause: though it's not necessary, but it make your query more clear

Comment: @ChristopherJones both mine and OP's examples use bind variables. Where do you see security risk and literals?

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov I've tried using the src alias for the SET, still it throws the column ambiguously defined. I'm unable to figure out from where. SQL --> 

link to the extracted SQL after replacing - https://pastebin.com/jpWr4Em8

Comment: Instead of looping and calling `execute()` multiple times, consider building up an array, and then using [`executemany()`](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html).

Comment: @Kulasangar just add `dst.` into `ON ( SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID = src.SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID ) ` ie it should be `ON ( dst.SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID = src.SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID ) `

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov I eventually intuited that was the intent, but it looks like col_names_as_str is used for VALUES.